RuntimeError: Unable to open file at PATH/TO/.tflite
I'm doing a project about translating manga and am following this repo: "https://github.com/tuhm1/transmanga"
I ran the python build.py file then installed the libraries in the pyproject.toml file, then I got this error when running the python main.py file
The detail error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Năm_4\Kì 2\Unemployer\Translate manga\transmanga-main\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    transmanga.__main__.main()
  File "D:\Năm_4\Kì 2\Unemployer\Translate manga\transmanga-main\transmanga\__main__.py", line 19, in main
    detector = mp.tasks.vision.ObjectDetector.create_from_options(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mediapipe\tasks\python\vision\object_detector.py", line 234, in create_from_options
    return cls(
           ^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mediapipe\tasks\python\vision\core\base_vision_task_api.py", line 70, in __init__
    self._runner = _TaskRunner.create(graph_config, packet_callback)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Unable to open file at D:\Năm_4\Kì 2\Unemployer\Translate manga\transmanga-main\transmanga\detector.tflite

And the code I think causes the bug in file transmanga/__main__.py:
detector = mp.tasks.vision.ObjectDetector.create_from_options(
        mp.tasks.vision.ObjectDetectorOptions(
            base_options=mp.tasks.BaseOptions(
                model_asset_path=pathlib.Path(__file__, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "detector.tflite")),
            ),
            score_threshold=0.5,
            running_mode=mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode.IMAGE,
        )
    )


Hi there, do you want to read the "detector.tflite" in your folder?

NB: the runtimeError you are facing is coming from the line 13 of your code.

Hi@nothing,Your error shows that script is unable to open the detector.tflite. You can use pathlib.Path(),it helps you to appends detector.tflite to the directory path.Second point check the file path you are putting is correct and read permissions .Try this if you still facing an issue let me know,Thanks.
